# load balancing IBM Liberty profile with apache http server

Tags: apache, load-balancing, websphere-liberty

I want to know how we can configure **Liberty Profile 8.5.5** (**Dev version** not the WAS ND version) to be load balanced by apache http server.

I have tried to search but havent been able to come across any useful links. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Vishalendu

Answer (score 3):

Currently, you'll have to generate a plugin-cfg.xml from each liberty server (the license has info about how many servers you can aggregate in this way for load balancing and failover) and merge the result to make it appear like a cluster to the WAS Plugin.

Other editions provide a merge tool, if you have access to them.

The WAS plugin installation has an XSD file for the plugin-cfg.xml.

1) note the http and https transports in both plugin configurations

2) make a copy of one of the XML's to edit

3) Find the <ServerCluster

```
<Config...
  <ServerCluster CloneSeparatorChange="false" GetDWLMTable="false" IgnoreAffinityRequests="true" LoadBalance="Round Robin" Name="cluster1" PostBufferSize="64" PostSizeLimit="-1" RemoveSpecialHeaders="true" RetryInterval="60" ServerIOTimeoutRetry="-1">
       <!-- copy generated Server stanza for your other XML -->
       <Server ...
       <PrimaryServers>
        <!-- add a 2nd primary server, from your other XML -->
         <Server Name="node1_serv1"/>
          ...
      </PrimaryServers>
  </ServerCluster>
```

4) Copy the  stanzas from the other file inside the ServerCluster

5) Add the servers name to the  field

If your servers have the same apps on them, you're done. Otherwise, you have to merge the other elements (Route, URIGroup, etc) but usually they'll be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will definitely try this out. The problem with using apache and WAS Plugin is that IBM support will not help, (in case you are facing issue with the plugin). They only support IHS + WAS combination. This is the reason we cant implement this in production env..

Comment: That is not true, the plugin gets the same commercial support in any supported webserver

Comment: I will have to log a PMR to verify that. AFAIK , IHS is the only supported webserver with WAS plugin.

Comment: Just to add to the explanation you have provided above,  more information on generating the plugin-cfg file can be found here : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_admin_webserver_plugin.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F1-3-11-0-3-2-6

Comment: I should add that my comments about plugin support were relative to  Apache vs IHS, not relative to whatever contents or usage restrictions your "developers version" might have.

Comment: Just to figure out the real deal, I have logged a PMR to find out for sure if IBM will support any issues with Liberty Dev Webserver plugin if used with Apache... if they dont, then it cant be used in production..